# How to Index artist/band names using lucene/solr out of my MySQL server

Tags: cakephp, solr, lucene, full-text-search, sharding

I'm interesting in indexing full names of artists/bands using Lucene/Solr out of my MySQL server.

I have a DB table called 'entity_aliases' which holds many variations of bands/artists in my system.
the table look like this:

```
entity_aliases int(11) auto inc. PK
entity_type enum(artist, band)
entity_id int(11)
entity_alias varchar(100) + full text search index.
```

Example entity_alias (field) values:

```
Beyoncé
Beyoncé Giselle Knowles
Giselle Knowles
...
```

**General explanation about the type of queries I'd like to perform:**

My service needs to provide information about artists/bands.
In order to do so - my clients need to provide me with the entity name.

*My clients (sometime) provide me an entity name with typos or a name that not found exactly in the DB (in our case "Beyonce Knowles" also note the European "é").

So the demands are:

1. I'm using sharded MySQL - so the 'entity_aliases' is also sharded. it need to index more than 1 MySQL server.
2. Its need to support 80M names.
3. Nice to have: ignore/overcome minor typos or European characters (fuzzy search).
4. Need to be supported by PHP (CakePHP).
5. entity names probably won't exceed 20-25 chars
6. The query itself is very simple - I provide a "name" and in return I'd like to get a list of similar entities (entity_id and entity_type) and if possible - a score.
7. I need to index entities on-the-fly and the index should be affect immediately.

**Things I'd like to know:**

1. is doable using lucene/solr?
2. is there any better solution that I need to consider?
3. how my schema should look like?

Thanks!

Comment: interesting question is difficult to find with typographical errors, in addition to names with the possibility of multiple languages. Maybe I can help in some of your problems, sphinx (http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds doable with solr.

Without going into the details you could convert accented characters into the ascii counterpart using a ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory

To search against words that sound similar but are misspelled you could use a PhoneticFilter http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PhoneticFilterFactory

You would need to play around with the different filters to see what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
can you suggest a schema please?